# Comparing Nullable long with Long in C#

Tags: c#, .net

What are we supposed to do when db column is Nullable long, here (Visit) and I have VisitorIds to compare with?

```
long[] VisitorIds = new long[] {1,2,3}; //an array to check with

    .Where(x => vivitorIds.Contains(x.Visit)).ToList();
```

If I convert to long in linq, it is throwing exception .

```
.Where(x => vivitorIds.Contains(Convert.ToInt64(x.Visit))).ToList();
```

Comment: From my personal experience: `Convert` always smells bad. Always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if the nullable has a value:

```
.Where(x => x.Visit.HasValue && vivitorIds.Contains(x.Visit.Value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`null conditional operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) with [`null coalescing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator),

```
//Considering long.MinValue is not a part of vivitorIds list.
.Where(x => vivitorIds.Contains(x?.Visit?.Value ?? long.MinValue)).ToList();
```

<sub>**Note:** This is just an alternate approach, Tim's solution is cleaner than this solution</sub>